# Ломается верстка при смене табов

Tags: html, jquery, css

Ребят помогите пожалуйста, второй день мучаюсь вот домен http://test2.posh.pro где верстка , трабла в вкладках Новые товары Популрные товары и Сезонные товары, сделал скрипт который разрешает клацать по этим табам все ок табы меняются, но когда кликаешь по какому то другому табу , в слайдере ересь какая то отображается код верстки

Код скрипта Jquery

```js
  $("#carousel").children().not(":first").hide();
  $(".mini-menu .primary-tab").click(function() {
    $(".mini-menu .primary-tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
    $("#carousel").children().hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
  }).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

Comment: Если кому интересно решение было вот таким http://css-live.ru/articles/eshhyo-chetyre-sposoba-skryt-i-pokazat-elementy-pri-pomoshhi-html-i-css.html

Answer (score 1):

Если кому интересно решение было вот таким http://css-live.ru/articles/eshhyo-chetyre-sposoba-skryt-i-pokazat-elementy-pri-pomoshhi-html-i-css.html вот код скрипта jquerry
 `$("#carousel").children().not(":first").css({"height":"0","overflow":"hidden"});
    $(".mini-menu .primary-tab").click(function() {
           $(".mini-menu .primary-tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
        $(".slider-wrapper").css({"height":"0","overflow":"hidden"}).eq($(this).index()).css('height','440px')
}).eq(0).addClass("active");`

Комментарий: Пользователь Vlad Vlad был абсоллютно прав что плагин слайдера не мог установить ширину слайдера, так как  прописывался в стилях display:none. 
Что было использовано: На основании пруфа выше мы элемент скрываем не display:none, а с помощью height: 0 и overflow: hidden. По клику мы этому элементу все возвращаем. Понимаю что может это костыль, но это работает.

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, из за того что у вас табы (кроме первого) скрыты, скрипт слайдера не может рассчитать ширину слайда, по этому он выставляете всем width: 0px. Вам надо поиграться со стилями, и найти обходной путь для того чтобы скрывать элементы, например свойство [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) - оно оставляет блок такой ширины|высоты которой он и есть, а добавив position absolute можно обойти проблему того что блок занимае место на странице, также надо блок спрятать на задний план (z-index) так как он остаеться кликабельным (по моему). Либо надо как-то дать возможность слайдеру сделать свое грязное дело до того как блоки будут скрыты (може еще у него есть функция перерасчета ширины).

Comment: Понял, спасибо за наводку, найду решение отпишусь